# How to integrate google cloud with dropbox and jupyter notebook using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter, google, cloud, pip

So I opened up a google cloud account and have access to global and local (us east 1) resources (Compute Engine API , NVIDIA K80 GPUs) and connected it to my dropbox.

Next, I followed [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMDQZPoMECE) to try to connect it to my jupyter notebook.

The code to be entered into the google cloud platform is as follows:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get - -assume-yes upgrade
sudo apt-get - -assume-yes install software-properties-common
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev build-essentials
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install jupyter
jupyter notebook - - generate-config
sudo nano ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

Insert these following lines under #configuration file for jupyter notebook
c=get_config()

```
c.NotebookApp.ip = ‘*’
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False (or True)
c.NotebookApp.port=1000
```

ctrl+alt? enter ctrl+x?
from 3.5.0.tar.gz you write tmux0.tar.gz
ctrl+b shift+double_course (to get two diff windows) or exit to go out of the double

```
jupter notebook password
jupyter notebook –no-browser –port=1000
```

And then you go to your browser and write external ip:port (ex. 35.197.7.72:1000)
At the top window, upload your environment

BUT, before running the following line:

```
sudo nano ~/.jupyter/jupter_notebook_config.py
```

It asks me if I want to overwrite .../jupyter/jupyte_notebook_config.py with default config, and with both scenarios (when entering yes and when entering no) after I run the line it says

> sudo: nano: command not found

I even tried to pip install nano and it worked (the installation) but still the same response - anyone know what I should do?

Comment: I'm unable to flag this as being more appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: `nano` is a text editor. You can use whatever text editor available (vim, gedit, ...) to edit the config file.

Answer (score 0):

The [python package `nano`](https://pypi.org/project/nano/) is not the text editor you need. Instead, you need the Ubuntu package `nano`. Try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nano
```

Comment: Thanks! Now, I continue with the following code:

'sudo nano ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py'

Insert these following lines under #configuration file for jupyter notebook
c=get_config()
c.NotebookApp.ip = ‘*’
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False 
c.NotebookApp.port=1000

'jupyter-notebook --no-browser --port=1000'

and it doesn't work (it did once this morning and since then, I've tried changing the port to 4000 or 5000 or 60) and the error I get is:

socket.gaierror: [Errorno -2] Name or service not known

Help, please?